# Exchange of the integral and exponentiation position

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

I have a quantity
$$q=\int_0^1\int_0^1 \exp \left({\int_0^1 f(x,y,z) dz}\right) dy dx $$
The question is whether I can find a function $g(x,y)$ such that
$$q= \exp \left(\int_0^1\int_0^1 g(x,y) dydx\right)$$
How big the error is assuming $\tilde{g}(x,y) = \int_0^1 f(x,y,z) dz$? Can I quantify $\|g - \tilde{g}\|$ or $q-\tilde{q}$ where 
$$\tilde{q}= \exp \left(\int_0^1\int_0^1{\int_0^1 f(x,y,z) dz}dydx\right)$$

If you would wonder about the application of it, it can be tracked to the Lambert-Beer law, where $f$ has a meaning of attenuation and $\exp{\int_0^1 f(x,y,z)} dz$ is connected to the intensity density of the ray along the $z$ axis. Computing $\tilde{q}$ is a common scheme of computational averaging intensities of all the rays going towards given detector pixel while physics based averaging is probably closer to $q$.

Comment: $g(x,y) = \log q$, a constant function, works trivially. What exactly do you know or not know about the quantities in practice? This is unclear in your post.